# Loop through an array while summing the output

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops

I am trying to use a **for** loop and then sum all of the outputs.  I know this is a basic question, but I am not sure if I should be trying to solve this within the loop or using another array.

For example:

```
for i in 1..100
if foo / 2 == 0
#find the sum of all outputs
end
```

end

Comment: You need to provide some more context. What do you mean by "outputs"? Where are you getting the numbers you need to add together?

Comment: I suggest `2*(1+50)*50/2 #=>  2550`. Benchmarks, anyone?

Comment: I think you mean the second line in your code to be `if i % 2 == 0`. SO won't let me make the edit.

Comment: Don't use `for`. Use `each` or one of the other looping constructs.

Comment: Thanks everyone, sorry for not being very specific, first question on SO, will make things more clear next time!

Comment: Yes, like @theTinMan said, using the `each` loop is better; it's the ruby way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
(2..100).step(2).inject(:+) #=> 2550
```

Or:

```
2.step(100,2).inject(:+) #=> 2550
```

You can use `sum` instead of `inject(:+)` from Ruby 2.4+

Comment: You don't need `to_a`. That's because the class [Range](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html) `include`s `Enumerable` and implements [Range#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html#method-i-each).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but my initial understanding is that you want to sum all of the numbers in a range (1..100) that meet a specific condition. In this case, something divided by 2 cannot equal zero aside from zero itself. I'm wondering if you meant %2, in which case, you're asking to sum all the even numbers in the range 1..100. This can be accomplished by doing the following.

```
    (1..100).select {|x| x if x.even?}.reduce(:+)
```

Effectively, you want to enumerate over a range and select only the numbers that meet your condition, as specified in the block. Calling reduce and passing it an accumulator.

Comment: `(1..100).select(&:even?).reduce(:+)` would be a cleaner version.